# Does endogeneity imply heteroskedasticity?

Tags: conditional-expectation, conditional-variance

Consider two random variables $X,Y$, with supports $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$, respectively, finite for simplicity.

Assume that the map
$$
x\in \mathcal{X} \mapsto E(Y|X=x)\in \mathbb{R}
$$
is not a constant function of $x$.

Does this imply that the map
$$
x\in \mathcal{X} \mapsto Var(Y|X=x)\in \mathbb{R}^+
$$
is not a constant function of $x$?

---

My attempt: I believe that the answer is NO.
In fact, I note that
$$
Var(Y|X=x)\equiv E(Y^2|X=x)-(E(Y|X=x))^2
$$
Then $Var(Y|X=x)$ can still be a constant function of $x$ provided that the difference between $E(Y^2|X=x)$ and $(E(Y|X=x))^2$ is maintained constant cross $x$. Could you confirm?

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Juste take

$$
Y=  X
$$
then
$$
\mathbb E(Y \mid X=x) = x
$$

While
$$
\text{Var}(Y \mid X=x) = 0
$$